# How do you access an object instance in the second parameter of the Mootools fireEvent function?

Tags: javascript, events, mootools

I'm working through **Implements: [Events, Options]** in Mootools.

I would like to pass a class property to the function that is called when an event fires. I would have thought that I could do it using ***this*** but ***this*** is undefined.

I have commented the code below where my problem is. I have a feeling that this might be to do with **binding** so I will be having a look at that now. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
var Person = new Class({

    Implements: [Options, Events],

    initialize: function(options){
        this.setOptions(options);
    }

});

greet = function(name){
    log('Hello, I am ' + name);
}

var ryan = new Person({
    name: 'Ryan',
    onArrive: greet //add event 'arrive'
});
ryan.fireEvent('arrive', ryan.options.name); //ideally I would use this.options.name?
```

This code works but it just seems strange to use the object instance name instead of ***this*** in the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fire the event this ***is*** your instance of ryan.
To make it work just make the following changes

```
function greet(name){
    log('Hello, I am ' + this.options.name); //<-- use this here 
}

ryan.fireEvent('arrive');
```

but since greet now depends on the instance it would be better to include it in your class definition

```
var Person = new Class({

    Implements: [Options, Events],

    initialize: function(options){
        this.setOptions(options);
    },
    greet: function() { log('Hello, I am ' + this.options.name); //<-- use this here  }
});
```

and

```
var ryan = new Person({
    name: 'Ryan',
    onArrive: this.greet.bind(this)  //or a function() { /* log('Hello,... */}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the `this` keyword refers to the *current object*. In your case, `this` probably refers to the global object (window). You have to be in the `ryan` instance scope  so that you can refer to `ryan` as `this` :

```
function fireEvent(e){
    this.fireEvent(e,this.options.name);
}
fireEvent.call(ryan,'arrive');
```

You could also overload the `fireEvent` method if you don't want to use a reference to the same instance again. Something like this :

```
var originalFireEvent = Person.prototype.fireEvent;
Person.prototype.fireEvent = function(e,o){
    var a = typeof this.options[o] !== 'undefined' ? this.options[o] : null;
    return originalFireEvent.call(this,e,a);
}
```

and then call it like this :

```
ryan.fireEvent('arrive','name');
```

Comment: this is not very moo-ish, it is not how fireEvent works - by default, callbacks are bound to the instance and not window.

Comment: I'm not talking about the reference inside the `fireEvent` function, but about the one when setting the arguments (you can call your function in any other scope). It has nothing to do with mootools.. it's all about standard javascript.

Comment: it is all to do with mootools when you are changing the prototype of the fireEvent method. making it always bind to instance, when it does not have to... the proper/accepted way to do it is what @jermel suggested. and yes, in javascript, you can do anything you like, does not mean it's the right thing to do in the context of a mootools class and its instances. https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Class/Class.Extras.js#L66-76 - you are killing Specs behavior, see arg 3 (delay). you should add a new method fireCustomEvent that relies on the original proto